# Android: how to achieve Material Design specs look with a standard Switch?

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-switch

I want to achieve a look like this (from the material design [specs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/selection-controls.html#selection-controls-switch)) for my switch when it's in the off state:

[image]

notice that the thumb is white and has a black outline with a slight shadow. I haven't been able to replicate this at all - much less to replicate the "focused" and "pressed" states with the halo around the thumb. What is the correct way of doing this? Do I need to work with 9-patches or is there a way to do it just using themes and xml? I want to support api 16 and up, but I noticed that Switch supports 14 and up so that shouldn't in itself be an issue.

Code for my current switch:

```
                        <Switch
                        android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        />
```

In my app Styles.xml:

```
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/myColor</item>

    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="android:colorForeground">@android:color/white</item>
```

Comment: switchcompat supports v7 and up but I only need v16 and up. Why is switchcompat preferable in this case?

Comment: The Material Design style of the Switch widget was introduced in Lollipop (api 21) and above. SwitchCompat gives you the Material Design style on the Switch widget, all the way back to v7 devices.